# gcp classic loadbalancer vs modern loadbalancer doesn't work with websocket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, websocket, load-balancing

We are having some issues with getting websockets to work with a load balancer in google cloud. We narrowed it down to a difference between the classic load balancer (works fine) and the `Https Loadbalancer with advanced traffic management` that is selected by default but marked as a preview (does not work).

We have an instance group that definitely supports websockets. I.e. we can connect to it via the ip address.

We set up a load balancer and went for the one with traffic management. That worked fine for normal requests but all the websocket requests fail with a `502`. We did not select `http/2` (which is documented as not working for this). We tried all sorts of things to get this working. Even though it is documented that this should work out of the box it clearly doesn't.

```sh
$ websocat wss://lb.tryformation.com/websocket/messages
websocat: WebSocketError: Received unexpected status code (502 Bad Gateway)
websocat: error running
```

As a last resort, I then set up a classic lb with the same configuration, same instance group, same health check, same certificate, etc. And this worked on the first try.

So, clearly the new style loadbalancer does not work as advertised when it comes to websockets. The question is: why? Is this a known issue or is there something I should configure to get websockets working with that?

We're fine using the classic lb as it works. But I would like to understand the issue.

Comment: Please update your question with more details about the configuration that you tested (working & and not-working) so we can try to analyaze it.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW:

Assuming you're using GCP's Global External HTTP(S) "modern" Load Balancer, the documentation states under [GCP CLB Overview > WebSocket support](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#websocket_support) states:

> - The global external HTTP(S) load balancer with advanced traffic management capability does not support Websockets. Websockets work with the global external HTTP(S) load balancer (classic) and regional external HTTP(S) load balancer as expected.

If you're using the regional "modern" LB, keep in mind that these "modern" Load Balancers are still in Preview. I'm sure you've seen this, but I'm only noting this because I've had experience with GCP products in the past that claimed to "support websockets" while in "Preview", but didn't work correctly until avaiable in GA.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide more details It's impossibler to reproduce it - hence try to conclude anything - there are just too many variables.

From your description it looks like some issue with traffic management in https load balacing - if you can reproduce it you can at Google's IssueTracker - [under the load balancing component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187245&template=1162973) and describe the issue in more detail; provide detailed reproductions steps and if possible your setup that you used (or any other details that  - after that someone will get back to you :)

Comment: Not really. We just went with defaults. Basically the documentation says websockets should work without fiddling with anything and that's clearly not the case. It's a load balancer with a wildcard certificate pointing to an instance group with a spring server capable of answering websocket requests. If I do the same with the classic LB it works fine (same instance group). I created the question here. I'm not currently putting any work in getting the new LB working so hard to pull out exact configuration for that. We basically gave up on it. So kind of reluctant to start creating more issues.

Comment: If something in GCP doesn't work as described in the documentation please report it to Google directly and this is what I meant in my answer. I changed the phrasing a little bit so there's no confusion where the issue should be reported.